Configuring nginx to work with separately containerized frontend and backend
The problem is that I have a separately containerized frontend and backend for my full stack web app (vue3, node, express, vite, axios). When running locally without a container, I can connect the front end with the back end using the vite.config.js file. For example, on the front end I would have something like this:
 try {
      axios
      .post("/addItem", { title : currList.value, text : newData.value, done : false })
      .then((response) => {
        this.result = response.data.result;
      }, (error) => {
        throw error || new Error(`Request failed`);
      })
    } catch(error:any) {
      console.error(error);
      alert(error.message);
    }

then in the vite.config.js file, I have this:
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  server: {
        proxy: {
            '/addItem': {
                target: 'http://localhost:3000',
                changeOrigin: true,
                secure: false,
                ws: true,
            },
        },
    } 
})


And in the backend server.js file I have this:
//add items to the todo list
  app.post('/addItem', (req, res) => {
  //do stuff here
  res.status(200).json({ result: req.body.text });
})

This works fine when running locally, non-containerized
So when I tried containerizing everything, It all seems to work other than input from the front end doesn't get to the backend. I believe it is an nginx problem. Here is what my file looks like:
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /addItem {
        proxy_pass http://server:3000;
    }
}

I've tried changing my vite.config.js file from localhost to server, but that doesn't seem to fix the issue. Anyone worked on a project like this? I can't find any examples online of someone with frontend and backend on separate ports (and separate containers) trying to send data between them when they are in docker containers

Can you share Dockerfiles and docker-compose.yaml and also the log with exact error message?

"Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend describes a sample setup somewhat like this, at least with separate front- and back-end containers an an Nginx reverse proxy.  The important trick in my answer there is that the call in the browser application doesn't include a host name at all, so it uses the current host and port.  I don't know if it's possible to omit the target: in your Vite configuration to work like this.

Yeah the error when inspecting element when loaded on a browser is: [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (addItem, line 0)
[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404

And the Dockerfile for the server is:
`# Use the official Node.js image as the base image
FROM node:16
Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app
Copy package.json and package-lock.json to the working directory
COPY package*.json ./
Install dependencies
RUN npm install
Copy the rest of the application code to the working directory
COPY . .
Expose the port the app runs on
EXPOSE 3000
Command to run the application
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:server"]`

Dockerfile for frontend:
FROM node:16 AS build WORKDIR /app COPY package*.json ./ RUN npm install COPY . . RUN npm run build FROM nginx:stable-alpine COPY --from=0 /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf EXPOSE 80 CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:app" ]

And the docker-compose.yml:
`version: '3.8'
services:
server:
build:
context: ./server
dockerfile: Dockerfile
ports:
- "3000:3000"
environment:
- PORT=3000
- MONGO_URI=mongodb://mongo:27017/todo-list
depends_on:
- mongo
networks:
- app-network
frontend:
build:
context: ./vue-app
dockerfile: Dockerfile
command: nginx -g 'daemon off;'
ports:
- "80:80"
depends_on:
- server
networks:
- app-network
networks:
app-network:
driver: bridge
`
